# Mime4j why doesn't appear getBody

Tags: android, mime

I add the mime4j jar to my Android project but for this code, Eclipse doesn't let to write. I mean there is no property or something else belongs to mime4j jar.

```
public static Part findFirstPartByMimeType(Part part, String mimeType)
            throws MessagingException {
        if (part.getBody() instanceof Multipart) {  // It says there is no getBody
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart)part.getBody();
            for (int i = 0, count = multipart.getCount(); i < count; i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                Part ret = findFirstPartByMimeType(bodyPart, mimeType); 
                if (ret != null) {
                    return ret;
                }
            }
        }
```

Or is there anyway for receive mail body with mime4j?